# Unable to use *= python operator in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm not sure why I'm unable to use the `*=` operator in a list comprehension, when using it in a `for` loop is fine?

```
def funcLC(l):
    ans = 1
    [ans *= x for x in l if x < 0]
    return ans

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

def funcFor(l):
    ans = 1
    for x in l:
        if x < 0:
            start *= x
    return ans
```

Comment: List comprehensions are not just the cool kids' way of writing loops. They're for *building lists*. If you aren't trying to build a list, list comprehensions are not the tool for the job.

Comment: I didn't know that before, and now I do, so thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment operator (and all variations on it) forms a *statement* in Python, not an *expression*. Unfortunately, list comprehensions (and other comprehensions, like set, dictionary and generators) only support expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can approach it with [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> from functools import reduce  # needed if Python 3.x
>>>
>>> l = [-1, 2, 4, 1, -3]
>>> reduce(mul, filter(lambda x: x < 0, l), 1)
3
```

A related tip: one of the indicators for using `reduce()` is that you have multiple values, but need to produce a single value out of it.

Comment: That's great thanks Alexce