# Using starred expressions with variables

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I intend to strip words linked by `"-"` in a words list.
I would use **starred expression** because I ignore if i will obtain a list among the list with `split()`.

I work well with constant expression:

```
[i for i in [*['1','2'],'1']]
```

yield:

```
['1', '2', '1']
```

I would obtain the same process with variables :

```
test=pd.DataFrame( {'columns0' :[['hanging', 'heart', 't-light', 'holder']]})
test.apply(lambda x : [e if len(e.split('-'))==1 else (*e.split('-')) for e in x ])
```

but as you expected it doesn't work :

```
  File "<ipython-input-1109-dda6b3df14bb>", line 3
    test.apply(lambda x : [e if len(e.split('-'))==1 else ( *e.split('-')) for e in x ])
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: `split` will always return a list. You might want to look at `itertools.chain` and check if e is a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even bother differentiating those cases? `split` returns a list either way, regardless of the length. Just nest the comprehension:

```
lambda x: [token for e in x for token in e.split('-')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the answer is that splats just aren't supported in list comprehensions.

The PEP concludes the abstract saying: "This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although this has not been ruled out for future proposals."

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#id6

In an answer to a similar question, @Curtis Lustmore explains that: "The assignment operator (and all variations on it) forms a statement in Python, not an expression. Unfortunately, list comprehensions (and other comprehensions, like set, dictionary and generators) only support expressions"

Source: [Unable to use *= python operator in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650471/unable-to-use-python-operator-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: Very useful informations, I guess it answer the question: it's not possible and not planned thus far